# What is best practice for handling data integrity when using Haskell's Persistent library?

Tags: haskell, persistent, data-integrity

Lets say I have a basic model in my application for handling users:

```
User
  username Text
  password Text
  email Text
```

Based on these types I can store whatever I like (as long as it is `Text` obviously) to any of these fields. Say I want to begin enforcing some rules around what can and cannot be considered an email. I create this email module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Model.EmailAddress
  ( EmailAddress
  , parseEmailAddress
  ) where

import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as TL
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Builder as TL
import           Database.Persist
import           Database.Persist.Sql
import           Text.Shakespeare.Text (ToText (..))

newtype EmailAddress = EmailAddress (Either InvalidEmailAddress ValidEmailAddress)
  deriving (Show, Eq)

instance ToJSON EmailAddress where
  toJSON = String . toStrictText

instance FromJSON EmailAddress where
  parseJSON = withText "EmailAddress" (pure . parseEmailAddress)

instance ToText EmailAddress where
  toText (EmailAddress e) = either toText toText e

newtype ValidEmailAddress = ValidEmailAddress Text
  deriving (Show, Eq)

instance ToText ValidEmailAddress where
  toText (ValidEmailAddress t) = toText t

data InvalidEmailAddress = InvalidEmailAddress
  { invalidEmailAddressValue :: Text
  , invalidEmailAddressReason :: Text
  } deriving (Show, Eq)

instance ToText InvalidEmailAddress where
  toText = toText . invalidEmailAddressValue

parseEmailAddress :: Text -> EmailAddress
parseEmailAddress t = 
  -- super basic validation example
  EmailAddress $ case T.count "@" t of
    0 -> Left (InvalidEmailAddress t "Must contain @ symbol")
    1 -> Right (ValidEmailAddress t)
    _ -> Left (InvalidEmailAddress t "Contains more than one @ symbol")

instance PersistFieldSql EmailAddress where
   sqlType _ = SqlString

instance PersistField EmailAddress where
  fromPersistValue =
    decodePersistTextValue parseEmailAddress

  toPersistValue =
    PersistText . toStrictText

decodePersistTextValue :: PersistField a => (Text -> a) -> PersistValue -> Either Text a
decodePersistTextValue f = \case
  PersistByteString bs ->
    fromPersistValue $ PersistText (T.decodeUtf8 bs)
  v ->
    f <$> fromPersistValue v

toStrictText :: ToText t => t -> Text
toStrictText = builderToStrictText . toText

builderToStrictText :: TL.Builder -> Text
builderToStrictText = TL.toStrict . TL.toLazyText
```

I could now define my model like so:

```
User
  username Text
  password Text
  email EmailAddress
```

However, this does not stop me from writing a bad email address to the database. If the rules around what constitutes a valid email address changes, I can read them from the DB still, and previously valid emails will come out of the DB as invalid, and this is fine, I like this. However I cannot enforce (at the persistent level anyway) preventing writing an invalid email to the database, because `toPersistValue` has the type `a -> PersistValue`, I suppose I would have to enforce this a layer up (when data is coming into the app, form decoders, json decoders etc) to ensure when a `Left InvalidEmailAddress` appears the user is given an error.

This leads me to thinking, is this the best practice around enforcing data integrity when using persistent? is there a better approach? Should persistent not be involved at all? ie the field remains as a `Text` and it is down to the app to convert these fields when they're being accessed?

I would really like a way of writing my entities to the database in a type safe way that allows me to determine what to do in the situation where an invalid email is used to try and save my `User` type, I could throw an `error` in the `toPersistValue` implementation but this feels a bit dirty to me, and not very Haskell'y.

Comment: I would say using Persistent's template haskell system is already not very Haskell-y because you have already given up control of type definition. As far as I know you can't declare `User` type outside of the template system then pass it to Persistent to automate all the type classes you want. I see it as a tradeoff. It is convenient because it generates a lot of things for you, but you give up a certain amount of control.

Comment: I'm not sure that would really make a difference here, you would still have to define your own `PersistField` instance, which would come up against the same problem. I'm not the biggest fan of TH myself but I don't think that is the problem here.

Comment: I guess I was just trying to make you not feel bad for doing some un Haskell-y things hehe, but if I understand the problem I think there is a good solution. You can define an `EmailAddress` type which is just a newtype wrapper over `Text`, hide the constructor, then export a custom constructor `mkEmail :: Text -> Maybe EmailAddress` which is responsible for making sure it is valid email. Then you can be sure all values of `EmailAddress` are valid emails and you don't have to worry about it in to and from PersistValue.